# reading XML file with QDomElement and tag in c++

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I have an XML file like this:

`<studentsform>
<student Studentname="srikanth" Address="1-66-1" SSC_marks="75%" Inter_marks="82%" Btech_marks="65%" Mailid="srikanth.togara@gmail.com"/>
</studentsform>`

How can i read this XML file in to lineedits of qt designer

Please help me

Comment: You want to read values from tag attributes and then show this values in QLineedits which your GUI has? I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes Mr: Krill Chernikov .  what you understand is exactly correct ,  am trying for read data into my QLineedits   only .

Comment: You can use simple examples from [qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html) for how parse xml file and retrieve attributes. Then you can add this values to your QLineedits with method [setText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing through an xml file is fairly easy, but is not a trivial answer. Take a look [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405553&seqNum=2) for some instructions on how to parse the xml file.

For specific reading of (assuming you have moved to the correct location in the file) you can use something like this:

```
// Get and attribute with name 'Studentname', currentPos is a QDomElement*
QString retVal = currentPos->attribute("Studentname", "");
```

or you can get all the attributes and parse them manually using:

```
QDomNamedNodeMap attrMap = currentPos->attributes();
```